# Storing a Database Connection String in AWS Fargate Container

Tags: docker, security, go, aws-fargate, aws-secrets-manager

Right now I have a container for an API that I am looking to push to an AWS Fargate instance that has a connection string for a DB on a privately hosted server. For testing this has been stored in a string in my Golang program, but I don't really want to push that even with the program already compiled.

I have looked into using the GO AWS SDK for the SecretsManager, but I am not sure if that is the best way to go, or if it will even work like I am hoping it will. What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: As long as your firewall rules are set up appropriately, it shouldn't really matter.  I usually keep those types of things in environment variables.

Comment: Have you taken a look at Docker secrets? https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/

Comment: Isn't Docker Secrets a Swarm feature? You wouldn't be able to use it in conjunction with Fargate.

Comment: @bluescores there is a golang sdk that gives you access to secrets.

Answer (score 1):

Hardcoding things into the program is obviously never the best choice, so I share your pain and the need for something better, that could be:

1. **Define the connection string into an environment variable**. This solution does not keep the information "secret", so if it's something that you would not like to have it readable in any way, try with the next
2. **Define the connection string into Secrets Manager and refer to in the environment variable definition**

Doing this with CloudFormation we will have in the first case:

```
...
Environment:
  -
    Name: CONNECTION_STRING
    Value: 'YOUR VALUE'
...
```

While in the second case we would have:

```
...
Environment:
  -
    Name: CONNECTION_STRING
    Value: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:MySecret:SecretString:connection_string}}'
...
```